# As I change the base url without affecting the heritage

Tags: jquery, url, resize

I have the following code that is very good, but has a problem that changes my whole url and I just want to change the root:

Current URL:

**http://www.domain.com/country/**name-permalink-variable

By the following url:

**http://www.domain.com/mobile/es/country/**name-permalink-variable

My current jQuery:

```
var hrefs = ['http://www.domain.com/country/', 'http://www.domain.com/mobile/es/country/'];

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.cnt-wrapper a').attr('href', function() {
        return hrefs[$(window).width() < 480 ? 0 : 1];
    });
}).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the href, not changing it. You might want to try storing the last part of the url in a data attribute and appending it to the calculated root. Something like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.cnt-wrapper a').attr('href', function() {
        return hrefs[$(window).width() < 480 ? 0 : 1] + $(this).data('pathEnd');
    });
}).trigger('resize');
```